# Php appending to 2d JSON array and properly adding it to file

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm slowly starting to learn dealing with json files, and have run into two small problems.

I have a json file looking like this:

```
{ "foldery" : [
    {
      "foName": "website/img/post1",
      "files" : [
        "website/img/post1/a.jpeg",
        "website/img/post1/b.jpg",
        "website/img/post1/c.jpeg",
        "website/img/post1/d.jpg",
        "website/img/post1/e.jpeg",
        "website/img/post1/f.jpg",
        "website/img/post1/g.jpg",
        "website/img/post1/h.jpg"
      ]
    },
    {
      "foName": "website/img/postdrugi",
      "files" : [
        "website/img/postdrugi/20150530_111106.jpg",
        "website/img/postdrugi/20150530_113842.jpg",
        "website/img/postdrugi/20150530_131251.jpg",
        "website/img/postdrugi/20151022_165146.jpg"
      ]
    },
    {
      "foName": "website/img/eeeeeeeeeeee",
      "files" : [
        "website/img/postrzy/20151101_130349.jpg",
        "website/img/postrzy/20151101_132214.jpg",
        "website/img/postrzy/20151101_134512.jpg"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The file, as you can see contains paths to folders and to every image inside the certain folder.
Now in I'm using a file adding script. The script first creates a directory, and after that fills it with files. My goal is to write code which would automatically update the json with new values.

For this I've written an array which begins on dir creation:

```
  $desired_dir="website/img/".$name."/";
            $json = array(
              'foName' => $desired_dir,
              'files' => array()
            );
```

And stared pushing values to it on every file creation:

```
            (...)
            $json['files'][$i] = $filto;
            ++$i; //$i was beforehand started as equal 0
            echo "<p>". $file_name." Uploaded!".$filto." </p>";
```

Unfortunately upon **echo json_encode($json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);**
I get:

```
 {"foName":"website\/img\/aaaddd\/",
 "files":{"0":"website\/img\/aaaddd\/s\/bar.jpg"}}
```

instead of desired:

```
 {"foName":"website/img/aaaddd/",
 "files":["website/img/aaaddd/s/bar.jpg",
         "website/img/aaaddd/s/foo2.jpg",
         "website/img/aaaddd/s/bar2.jpg"]}
```

(for the upload of three files: bar, foo2 and bar2)
Note the missing *'"0":'*
So here are my two questions:

1. What could I do to make the json encode display the values which would fit in the array in json. With correct appending, cutting out the index number in the nested array
2. How can I correctly add such files into my .json file? (mind the { "foldery" :[ (..) at the beginning of the file)

Also, one bonus small one: Should I worry about the '/' instead of '/'? Overheard that for JSON both mean the same.

Any help would be amazing.

Edit: As requested. Here is the entire script which uploads the files into a given directory:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_FILES['files']) && isset($_POST['name'])){
      $json = array();

      $name = $_POST['name'];

        foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
            $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
            $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
            if($file_size > 12582912){
                $errors[]='File size must be less than 12 MB';
            }
            $desired_dir="website/img/".$name."/";

            $json = array(
              'foName' => $desired_dir,
              'files' => array()
            );
            if(empty($errors)==true){
                if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                    mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
                }

                if(is_dir($desired_dir."/s")==false){
                    mkdir("$desired_dir/s", 0700);      // Create directory if it does not exist
                }
                if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $desired_dir.$file_name);
                    $filto= $desired_dir."s/".$file_name;
                    $filfrom= $desired_dir.$file_name;
                    smart_resize_image($filfrom , null, 400 , 400 , true , $filto , false , false ,100 );
                    $json['files'][] = $filto;
                  //  echo "<p>". $file_name." Uploaded!".$filto." </p>";


                }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
                    $new_dir="website/img/".$file_name.time();
                     rename($file_tmp,$new_dir);
                     echo "<p>". $file_name." Uploaded! </p>";

                }



            }else{
                    print_r($errors);
            }
        }
        if(empty($error)){
        echo json_encode($json);
            echo "<h2>Success</h2>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Try $json['files'][] = $filto; instead of $json['files'][$i] = $filto;

Comment: Tried it but still only displays one row of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` You're telling `json_encode()` to return the data as an object at all times instead of an array, hence you see the `0` index which you had appended to `files`.

From php.net,

> JSON_FORCE_OBJECT (integer) :
>       Outputs an object rather than an array when a non-associative array is used. Especially useful when the recipient of the output is
>   expecting an object and the array is empty. Available since PHP 5.3.0.

Remove the flag, and you will see the desired data without 0 indexes, as to why you are seeing just one data in your array could have something to do with how you're pushing the directory path to the main array in your loop.

Fiddle: https://eval.in/535407

**EDIT**
You are re-instantiating the $json variable everytime in your loop, place it outside the loop ,

```
 $json = array(
  'foName' => '',
  'files' => array()
 );
 ...
 foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
  ....
  $desired_dir="website/img/".$name."/";
  $json['foName'] = $desired_dir;
  ....
  ..
```

Comment: Yes, this option worked! Thank you. Still trying to figure out how to place multiple items into the second array. thepieterdc's option did not work

Comment: can you update your question with more code please ? I cannot see the loop code where you save it in to $json array

Comment: Added the entire uploading function

Answer (score 1):

Move this out of your loop, so it comes before it:

```
       $json = array(
          'foName' => $desired_dir,
          'files' => array()
        );
```

To get this:

```
    $json = array(
      'foName' => $desired_dir,
      'files' => array()
    );
  foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
        if($file_size > 12582912){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 12 MB';
        }
        $desired_dir="website/img/".$name."/";
        $json['foName'] = $desired_dir;
        /// etc...
```

Because now every iteration you destroy the previous result that was put in the `files` arrray.

As said, you need also to remove the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` argument from the call to `json_encode` is it will convert arrays to objects, resulting in properties like `0`.

Comment: Your answer works, but Vincent was first. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Sure, no problem. Good luck!